# Is it possible to pull 600,000 rows from a MySQL database and Display it as JSON data in postman?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, postman

I am trying to return a MySQL table with 600,000 rows and display it as a JSON object. My views.py contains the method below.

```
def SettlementsStatements_1(request, query=""):    
    if query =="All":
        namemap={'ID':'id','Comapny Name':'COMPANY_NAME'}
        ssr=SettlementsStatements.objects.raw('SELECT id,COMPANY_NAME FROM telco_amazon.settlements_statements;',translations=namemap)
        data = serializers.serialize('json', ssr)



    return JsonResponse(data,safe=False)
```

I am calling this view in postman and it has yet to load after 40 minutes.I am wondering, is it even possible to extract and load this much data?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use a JSON message to return such a large dataset? From what I've seen implemented, JSON messages are intended to be smaller unless you intend to utilize pagination...

Comment: I want to try to get this table to be loaded into grid on a web app. So, I am trying to do it without pagination.

Comment: I think you are going to have to re-evaluate your approach considering the performance implications both from the user side as well as on the back end. Pulling 600k records is pretty intensive just from the DB side alone. Then on the client side, you will be tasking the client with rendering such a large number of records as well. All in all, thats a pretty big amount of data to be pulling and presenting routinely... You may want to start looking for ways to automatically narrow the results (i.e. filtration)